# Пакетное редактирование файлов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, unix, macos, sed

Есть проект, в котором много файлов, как можно добавить одинаковую строку в каждый файл проекта? Ручками делать совсем не хочется)

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Куда вставить - в начало файла, в конец файла, после определённой строки? Нужно вставить во все файлы или в файлы какого-то определённого типа, например служебные файлы проекта? (Можно уточнить, какой проект)

Comment: Нужно вставить в начало файла, файлы расширения js и jsx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться, например, программой *sed*:

```
$ sed -i '1s/^/эта строка будет первой\n/' *.js *.jsx
```

не забудьте перед её выполнением сделать резервную копию файлов.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, реализовал скрипт таким образом:
`find app -type f -name "*.jsx" | while read FILENAME; do
gsed -i '1s/^/import settings from "settings\/settings";\n/' $FILENAME 
echo "$FILENAME"
done

find app -type f -name "*.js" | while read FILENAME; do
gsed -i '1s/^/import settings from "settings\/settings";\n/' $FILENAME 
echo "$FILENAME"
done`
Скрипт рекурсивно перебирает все файлы в директории app, выбирает только .js и .jsx файлы и вставляет в начало этих файлов строку. Может подскажите, как можно это реализовать более изящно?