# sed, замена во всем проекте?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, find

Система: **macOS**
файлы: **html, css, js**.
`grep "text" -R ./*` — этот код находит все необходимое для замены.
Дальше попробовал:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "text" -exec sed -i '' "s/text/TEXT/g" {} \;
```

и

```
grep "text" -R ./* -exec sed -i '' "s/text/TEXT/g" {} \;
```

Как сделать замену в разных типах файлах, во всех каталогах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> find . -maxdepth 2 -name "text" -exec sed -i '' "s/text/TEXT/g" {} \;
> ```

вы почти угадали. только надо ограничить тип объекта (вам ведь только файлы нужны) и убрать ограничение на имя объекта файловой системы.

примерно так (обратите внимание: в операционных системах, отличных от *gnu*, версия программы *gnu/sed*, имеющая опцию `-i`, обычно называется *gsed*):

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec gsed -i "s/text/TEXT/g" {} \;
```

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec sed -i '' "s/text/TEXT/g" {} \;
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`...

Comment: а, так у вас, видимо, кастрированная версия программы sed. поставьте нормальную, из операционной системы gnu.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/611378/178576

Comment: brew upgrade sed
Error: No available formula with the name "sed"
===
brew uninstall sed
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/sed
в Linux, разобрался бы как пересобрать, macOS знаю только три команды:
brew upgrade;
brew install;
brew uninstall;

Comment: gnu-версия sed, наверно, называется `gsed`

Comment: Переустановил.
Тот же принцип что и в Linux
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
===
работает без ''
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec sed -i "s/text/TEXT/g" {} \;

Comment: речь про опцию `-i`, которая присутствует только в реализации программы *sed* из операционной системы *gnu*: [GNU sed имеет несколько новых особенностей, например замещающая правка файлов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)